# Help with alpha-cuts in fuzzy sets

Tags: fuzzy-set

basically all I need to know is what are the standard methods to achieve the below.

So, I have a fuzzy set A containing (say) four elements. For each element I have a degree of membership. The degrees of membership sum to one. I want to get a crisp version of A. 
I'm aware we have alpha-cuts. But is there any standard method to find alpha?

(in a nutshell: the elements are actually features in a data set, and the degrees of membership is how relevant each feature is. I'm trying to do feature selection here.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Given a fuzzy set $A$ on an universal set $X$, their $\alpha$-cuts are defined as follows:
$A_\alpha=\{x\in X\ | \ A(x)\geq\alpha\}$

Therefore, taking $\alpha$ as the degrees of the elements, you have different  crisp  subsets of $X$.

In particular, for $\alpha=0$ you have $A_\alpha=X$.